# How to setup a Docker container for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, docker

I really like the idea of packing my favourite Eclipse setup inside a tiny, portable, gittable Dockerfile. I already know how to setup a base Ubuntu desktop OS + Java + base eclipse package. However, I need a way to install Eclipse plugins from the command line.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Use the P2 Director application to install the plug-in and features as needed, just remember that features need ".feature.group" appended to their IDs when you specify them (otherwise it'll look for a bundle by that name). `-repository` and `-installIU` can both take comma separated lists of values.

https://help.eclipse.org/stable/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_director.html